# Send GET request from xmlHttpRequest to php file Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I was trying to execute php file using `xmlHttpRequest` in order to send GET request. Sadly, it always returns me error : `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

This is my `index.js` file

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

This is how I send GET request

```
var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("This is response text " + this.responseText)
    } else {
        console.log("This is code " + this.responseText)
    }
};
xmlRequest.open("GET","app.php?token=" + data, true)
xmlRequest.send()
```

This is my `php` file which in the same directory like `index.js`

```
<?php

 $device = $_GET['token'];
 $deviceToken = $device;
 echo $device;
```

Comment: How did you determine that your server is actually running?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am using `npm start` to run local server. And there is `post` request which I sent via postman and then base on data that I sent via `postman`, I want to execute php file by passing data that I sent from `postman`  using GET request

Comment: Sorry to ask so dumb, but I've never tried that: are you sure that a local npm server is able to handle PHP files?

Comment: I also not sure about it. That's why I dare to ask a question here. Sorry, if I have a mistake

Comment: If you haven't configured it to work like that, I would assume that you should do that. And if there is no way to configure the npm server command like that, you should use something like nginx or Apache

Comment: Thank for your advice. I will try to figure it out

Comment: You also need to run a server for PHP. So, essentially you'll have two ports running on your local system. Let's say port 6060 for Node.JS and port 8080 for PHP. You already started the Node using npm start. You also need to have an apache or nginx server for PHP to run on. If you're using XAMPP stack, it should be pretty easy apart from some apache configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` is used to send request to particular server. But your question is about to execute php file which that php file located in your `node` project.

If I am not mistaken I would like to suggest library named `exec-php`. Here is [link](https://github.com/iqbalfn/exec-php) for that library. Hope it help.